# When using PayPal, we DON'T want to collect credit card info!

Tags: paypal, security

I've searched for the answer to this, but haven't found it. Our issue is we want to have a contribution page with PayPal and Pay Later capability but don't want credit card information entered on our server.

I've just set up a contribution page, and the PayPal section requests all the credit card information be entered ON OUR SERVER before going to PayPal to complete the transaction. We really don't want this info on our servers, even temporarily!

For event ticket sales, choosing PayPal for the fees sends us to PayPal where the PayPal account or other credit card information is then entered on their servers. This is the way we would like the contribution pages to work.

Am I doing something wrong here? I can't remember ever seeing a credit card information form on any of my sites.

We're running CiviCRM 5.32.2 on Wordpress.

Thanks,
Rick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've not tried all these options out, but looking at the documentation for Payment Processors ([user guide](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/contributions/payment-processors/) and [system administrators guide](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/payment-processors/#comparison) there is more than one PayPal payment processor. With PayPal Standard all the credit card details are collected on the PayPal site and with PayPal Pro they are collected on your site and transferred by SSL but not kept. There is also PayPal express. I suspect that you maybe using different Payment Processors for your two cases. Certainly worth checking what you have and adding that to the question. I'm not sure what the relevance of Pay Later is having never used that, but I think that's for offline collection of the payment.

Comment: So Mick was correct. I had indicated we had PayPal Pro, and that provided the "feature" that we could collect credit card info on our website. We just don't want to do that, so setting it to PayPal standard modified the way it works. It's now what we wanted - the credit card number collection is handled by PayPal servers. Thanks Mick!